# Like Count Query Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've two collection in mongoose collection A and Collection B

Collection A(User) :

```
{
 id : 1,
 Name : User1,
},
{
  id: 2,
  Name :  User2
},
{
 id: 3,
 Name: User3
}

collection B(Item) :
{
 id :1,
 name : Item1
},
{
 id: 2,
 name: Item2
}


Collection C(ItemLikes)
{
 id : 11,
 isLike : true,
 userId : 1,
 itemId : 1,
}
{
 id:12,
 isLike : true,
 userId : 2,
 ItemId : 1
},
{
 id:13,
 isLike : false,
 userId : 3,
 ItemId : 1
},
{
 id:14,
 isLike : false,
 userId : 3,
 ItemId : 2
}
```

Now I need the following output

```
 {
   ItemId : 1,
   totalLikes(true) :  2,
   isYourLike : true,
   userId: 1
 }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$group` if you only want to survey item 1

- `$match` find itemId is 1
- `$group` group by item 1 and use condition sum in it
- `$project` change `isYourLike` into boolean

```
db.itemLikes.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "itemId": 1
    },
    
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$itemId",
      "isYourLike": {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$isLike",
                    true
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$userId",
                    1
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      "totalLikes(true)": {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$isLike",
                true
              ]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "itemId": "$_id",
      "isYourLike": {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $gte: [
              "$isYourLike",
              1
            ]
          },
          then: true,
          else: false
        }
      },
      "totalLikes(true)": 1
    }
  }
])
```

**Example： [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1IbmygA7s_j)**

---

Use `$lookup` if you want count every item

- `$lookup` join different collection
- `$project` condition sum in it
- `$project` change `isYourLike` into boolean

```
db.item.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "itemLikes",
      "localField": "id",
      "foreignField": "itemId",
      "as": "likes"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "itemId": "$id",
      "totalLikes(true)": {
        "$size": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$likes",
            "cond": {
              "$eq": [
                "$$this.isLike",
                true
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "isYourLike": {
        "$size": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$likes",
            "cond": {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$this.isLike",
                    true
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$this.userId",
                    1
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "itemId": "$itemId",
      "isYourLike": {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $gte: [
              "$isYourLike",
              1
            ]
          },
          then: true,
          else: false
        }
      },
      "totalLikes(true)": 1
    }
  }
])
```

**Example： [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/V1VZnbiDBo9)**